# Proof using Fermat's Theorem on stationary points?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives

It seems intuitive that, if a function differentiable on [a,b] is such that f'(a) < 0 < f'(b) then there exists some c in the open interval (a,b) such that f'(c)=0, but I can't prove it rigourously...

I expect to need to use Fermat's Theorem on stationary points but I would then need to prove that c is a local extremum.

Am I on the right path or totally wrong? Can you hint me?
Thank you

Comment: Ok, why not to finish to write the question before posting it...? :)

Comment: I did, but it didn't make it for some reason ^^ Sorry, now it's complete ;)

Comment: The usual informal statement of the result is that although the derivative is not necessarily continuous, it always has the Intermediate Value Property.

Answer (score 2):

This is the Famous [Darboux's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_%28analysis%29).

The idea of the proof is that if $f'(a)<0$, then there is a $x_1>a$, where $f(x_1)<f(a)$.
similarly, as $f'(b)>0$, there is a $x_2<b$, with $f(x_2)<f(b)$. Hence neither $f(a)$ nor $f(b)$ are the minimum values of $f$, and thus its minimum is achieved in an interior point $c$, where the derivative vanishes.

Comment: Oww, yes I see! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$$f'(a)<0<f'(b)\implies \;\exists\,c,d\in (a,b)\;\;s.t.\;\;f\;\;\text{is descending in}\;\;[a,c)$$

$$\text{and ascending in}\;\;(d,b]$$

By continuity, there's some point in between (between *what*?) in which $\;f\;$ must have an extrema (in fact, a local minimum)

Comment: I thought this way but could not prove the => rigourously.